# c++ pushback first vector and sorting vectors by ascending order

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I'm trying to sorting first vectors
vector l[0] are points of x1, then its length always change

```
vector<int> v1;
v1.push_back(l[0]);
vector<int>::iterator Iter = v1.begin();
for (Iter = v1.begin(); Iter != v1.end(); Iter++){
sort(v1.begin(), v1.end());
cout << *Iter << endl;
```

it didn't have any error but can't sorting by order. how can i solve it?

edit----------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
void thresh_callback(int, void*)
{

    /// Load source image and convert it to gray
    src = imread(img_file, 1);

    Mat threshold_output;
    Mat threshold_output1;
    Mat dst;
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;

    /// Detect edges using Threshold
    Canny(src_hist, threshold_output, thresh, thresh * 3, 3, false);
    Sharpen(threshold_output, threshold_output1);


    cvtColor(threshold_output1, dst, CV_GRAY2BGR);

    vector<Vec4i> lines;
    HoughLinesP(threshold_output1, lines, 1, CV_PI / 180, thresh1, min_line, max_gap);

    int erosion_size = 1;
    Mat element = getStructuringElement(MORPH_ERODE,
        Size(2 * erosion_size + 1, 2 * erosion_size + 1),
        Point(erosion_size, erosion_size));

    /// Apply the erosion operation
    dilate(dst, dst, element);

    imshow("Source", dst);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++)
    {
        Vec4i l = lines[i];
        Scalar color = Scalar(rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255));
        int dx = l[2] - l[0];
        int dy = l[3] - l[1];

        double rad = atan2(dx, dy);
        double degree = (rad * 180) / M_PI;

        if (degree >= 180) degree -= 180;
        if (degree < 15 || degree > 165) {
            line(src, Point(l[0], l[1]), Point(l[2], l[3]), Scalar(0, 0, 255), 1, 8);
            //printf("%lf\n", degree);
            //printf("%d, %d, %d, %d, %d\n", l[0], l[1], l[2], l[3], i);

            vector<int> v1;
            v1.push_back(l[0]);
            vector<int>::iterator Iter = v1.begin();
            sort(v1.begin(), v1.end());
            for (Iter = v1.begin(); Iter != v1.end(); Iter++){
                cout << *Iter << endl;
            }
        }
        imshow("source", src);
    }

}
```

I use houghline and find out point of x1,x2,y1,y2
and get every x1 and sort ascending

Comment: I'm sorry but it is very unclear what you want to do.

Comment: Also, why use single-letter variable names like `l`?  It looks like a `1`.

Comment: `for (Iter = v1.begin(); Iter != v1.end();){` infinite loop ? did u mean `for (Iter = v1.begin(); Iter != v1.end(); ++Iter){`

Comment: As is, after you fix all typos so that it actually compiles as in @VaibhavBajaj answer below, you will be sorting one `int` as that is all you `push_back` to `v1`. What do you actually want to sort?

Comment: can we have the smallest compiling program that shows the problem you are having? The code sample in your question is missing surrounding information that might be important to finding the problem.

Comment: Are you attempting to sort the first element of every line that has a degree of < 16 or > 165?

Comment: @jaggedSpire alright, i find out lines in certain degree

Answer (score 4):

Not sure that this is your problem but... you define `v1` inside a `for` loop.

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++)
{
  // ...

        vector<int> v1;
        v1.push_back(l[0]);
        vector<int>::iterator Iter = v1.begin();
        sort(v1.begin(), v1.end());
        for (Iter = v1.begin(); Iter != v1.end(); Iter++){
            cout << *Iter << endl;
        }
  // ...
}
```

So you, every iteration, create a vector, insert a single element, sort the vector (with a single element), print the single value and *destroy* the vector.

Suggestion: define `v1` outside the `for` loop.

**--- Edit ---**

As pointed by aichao, the sort and the print part are presumably better outside the for loop; something like

```
vector<int> v1;

for (size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++)
{
  // ...

        v1.push_back(l[0]);

  // ...
}

sort(v1.begin(), v1.end());

for ( vector<int>::const_iterator CIter = v1.cbegin(); CIter != v1.cend(); CIter++) {
   cout << *CIter << endl;
}
```

If you can compile C++11 or C++14, the last `for` can be simply

```
for ( auto const & i : v1 )
   cout << i << endl;
```

p.s.: sorry for my bad English.

Comment: @plzunderstandmyenglish Please Understand His English.

Comment: @max66: maybe you could edit this so that you move the `v1` definition **and** the `sort` and subsequent output outside the for loop?

Comment: @max66 thank you, i will try it

Comment: @aichao - you're right; modified my answer according it.

Comment: @plzunderstandmyenglish - modified my answer to follow the suggestion from aichao

Comment: @max66 oh it work thank you!!!!!

Comment: @plzunderstandmyenglish - modified the final example to use a const iterator and added a C++11 semplification